# How to count similar words from array with strpos function of php?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, strpos, pdftotext

I am using xpdf to convert pdf to text and then with help of regex function seraching for words after colon in pdf and then looping that data with strpos function of php and storing them into database.Its working for me for single data.
but for multiple same data i am not getting how to add this data into database.

step by step i will show you my code and response:

i am using xpdf to convert my pdf into text format with below code.

```
$text1 = (new Pdf('C:\xpdf-tools-win-4.00\bin64\pdftotext.exe'))
->setPdf($pathoffile)
->setOptions(['layout', 'layout'])
->text();
$string = $text1;
```

On `echo $string` i am getting data i.e:

```
                                 In respect of Shareholders

Name:                                    xyz

Residential address:                     dublin

No of Shares:                            40

Name:                                    abc

Residential address:                     canada

No of Shares:                            2
```

SO, i am getting total 2 shareholders with my above data. Now i want to store this data in my table `shareholders`.

Now, i am using preg_match_all function to convert this data into array and then storing into databaase.

```
$array = array('Name','Residential address','No of Shares');
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
```

Using below function for getting array with strpos().

```
function strposa($haystack, $needles=array(), $offset=0) {
        $chr = array();
        foreach($needles as $needle) {
                $res = strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset);
                if ($res !== false) $chr[$needle] = $res;
        }
        if(empty($chr)) return false;
        return min($chr);
}

if($this->strposa($text1, $array) !== false) 
                {
                    foreach ($matches as  $value) {
                        //print_r($matches);
                        $value=array_map('trim',$value);
                        $directors_info->name= $value[0];
                        $directors_info->address= $value[1];
                        $directors_info->shares= $value[2];
                      }
                }
```

My array of `print_r($matches)` shows me data :

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>              xyz
            [1] =>              dublin
            [2] =>              40
            [3] =>              abc
            [4] =>              canada
            [5] =>              2
        )
```

but if i am getting multiple shareholders then it will not work for me. My expected output would be:

```
[0] => Array
            (
                [0] =>              xyz
                [1] =>              dublin
                [2] =>              40
                [0] =>              abc
                [1] =>              canada
                [2] =>              2
            )
```

My concern is to store 2 data separately with 2 rows in  table. How to achieve this kind of data. thanks in advance.

Comment: You can not have duplicate keys like in the last array. Then you could create a multidimensional array.

Comment: yes right i know that thing. @Thefourthbird but how to achieve this any idea

Comment: I have added an answer how you might do that. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have duplicate keys, so you could create a multidimensional array. If the data for each row is always there, you could use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) with a size of 3:

```
$matches = array_chunk($matches,3);
```

That would give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => xyz
            [1] => dublin
            [2] => 40
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => abc
            [1] => canada
            [2] => 2
        )

)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/0QlGu)

Comment: how can add this data in table with foreach it stores only [0]th index.

Comment: If you click on the demo link, you will see the foreach where every `$value` is an array where you can get the values in those arrays by using the index 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: yes right i used your code. but it stores only 0th index in table

Comment: So you mean that you only store all the values of the first array (name, address and shares)? Did you do a `print_r($matches)` and do you see 2 arrays? When are you storing the data to the database?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53573638/how-to-store-array-in-table-split-by-array-chunk-in-php i create new question for this