# How to store array in table split by array_chunk in php?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, foreach

> I am getting data in array format.Some times i get duplicate data
>   after 2nd index. so i decide to split array in 3 index with
>   array_chunk function of php. But after doing this on foreach loop get
>   only 0th index. i want to store all 0th,1st,2nd.. in tables with new
>   row.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => xyz
            [1] => dublin
            [2] => 2
            [3] => yxd
            [4] => canada
            [5] => 2
        )

)
```

I am using array_chunk to split my array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Suhas shinde
            [1] => Jogeshwari
            [2] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Suhas shinde
            [1] => Jogeshwari
            [2] => 2
        )

)
```

Now, i have to store this in table. so i used foreach loop :

```
foreach ($matches as $value) 
{
    $share_holder_info->trad_id = $rand_id;
    $share_holder_info->name = $value[0];
    $share_holder_info->address = $value[1];
    $share_holder_info->shares = $value[2];
    $share_holder_info->save(); 
}
```

It stores only 0th index of array in table.

```
if (preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!\A)|In respect of Shareholders)\s*[^:\r\n]+:\h*\K.*~', $string, $matches)) {

    $matches = array_chunk($matches[0],3);
    //foreach loop
}
```

Comment: Your split array look **nothing like** your original array? Is there some magic invloved here that you are not showing us?

Comment: Please show the original array... Then the code that you use to split it..... then the new split array.

Comment: i added my code @RiggsFolly

Comment: Where and what is `$string`

Comment: string is my text my variable from where i am getting data . i am converting my pdf to text with xpdf

Comment: Also what does `$share_holder_info->save()` do, does this just do an INSERT or might it UPDATE?

Comment: this is my insert function. i am using laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your foreach to this to allow for the creation of new Model instance for each record set.

```
foreach ($matches as $value) {

    $share_holder_info = new ShareHolderInfo();
    $share_holder_info->trad_id = $rand_id;  
    $share_holder_info->name = $value[0]; 
    $share_holder_info->address = $value[1]; 
    $share_holder_info->shares = $value[2]; 
    $share_holder_info->save(); 

}
```

You will need to change it to what ever your actual Model is named.

I hope this helps

Comment: thanks for your reply but it shows me error `"Uninitialized string offset: 2` on line `$share_holder_info->shares = $value[2]; `

Comment: @amitsutar try my updated answer. I realised that your vetting the array values a different way.